# Change the background of Text dynamically in tableau

Tags: data-science, tableau-api, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

Is there a way we could change , the color of the background in tableau dynamically.
I have just used the Text Object , in text-Object I have taken name and < parameter >%.
I would like to change color based on parameter value .
Like less than 90% be Red and more than it be Green.
In image-below , I have hardcoded the values .
so , i want it in live that hence dynamic

[image][image][image]

Comment: Dynamic background changing is not supported in tableau, however there is a way around this using Gantt chart or shapes : https://youtu.be/YBt37jvOQ7g